# Prove that a given probability forms a probability measure with binomial distribution

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

I currently have some troubles in proving the given probability forms a probability measure for the following problem:

Assume we have $m$ distinct balls distributed to $n$ urns, and each of the $n^m$ distributions have equal probability. Given the probability of an urn $A$ containing exactly $k$ balls $(k=0,1,...,m)$, is $p_k = \frac{{m\choose k}(n-1)^{(m-k)}}{n^m}$. Show  that $p_k$ forms a **probability measure** binomial$(p, m)$ where $p = \frac{1}{n}$.

**My attempt:** We need to show that the $3$ following properties for $p_k$ is satisfied:

**(1)** $\ p_k = p(A_k)\geq 0$ where $A_k =$ an event when urn $A$ has exactly $k$ balls for $k=0,1,...,m$. This is trivially true given definition of $p_k$.

**(2)**  Need to show that $\ p(A) = 1$ where $A = \bigcup_{k=0}^{m} A_k$ is the sample space. But isn't this ALWAYS true?? If not, is all I need to do is to verify $\sum_{k=0}^{m} p_k = 1$? But to do this, I need to prove $p$ satisfies the 3rd property below.

**(3)** Need to show that for a countable union of disjoint sets ${A_k}$, $p(\bigcup_{k=0}^{m} A_k)\  = \ \sum_{k=0}^{m} p_k$? But isn't this also true by using Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion, since $m$ is fixed and {$A_{k}$}$_{k=0}^{m}$ are disjoint sets due to its definition?

Finally, from the formula of $p_k$, we could rewrite it as ${m\choose k}(1-\frac{1}{n})^{m-k}(\frac{1}{n})^k$, thus $p_k$ follows binomial distribution with $p = \frac{1}{n}$ and $n=r$.

**My question:** Could anyone help on proving step $(2)$ and $(3)$ above? I am quite confused since they all seem obviously true in this setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** In order to properly answer this problem, we have to clearly distinguish and precisely state three parts: assumption, claim and proof.

> - **Assumption:**
>
>   - We have $m$ distinct balls, distributed to $n$ urns giving $n^m$ distributions.
>   - We have marked a specific urn and identied by the name $A$.
>   - The probability $p_k$ that urn A contains $k$ balls is as you already noted
>       \begin{align*}
>      p_k= \binom{m}{k}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{m-k}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^k\qquad\qquad 0\leq k\leq m
>       \end{align*}
> - **Claim:**
>
>   - Show that $p_k$ forms a *probability measure* $\text{binomial}(p,m)$ with $p=\frac{1}{n}$
> - **Proof:**
>
>   In order to show that $p_k$ is a probability measure we have to specify the *sample space*, let's say $S$. Note the urn $A$ is *not* the sample space.
>
>   The sample space $S$ is the set of *all* possible outcomes, i.e. the set of number of balls in $A$ when distributing the $m$ balls in $n$ urns. We encode this by
>     \begin{align*}
>   S=\{0,1,2,\ldots,m\}
>   \end{align*}

Regarding OPs remark in (2): *isn't this ALWAYS true?*

This is not the appropriate question. A sample space is not explicitly given. So, we have to *define* it and since it is a part of our proof we have to argue that our definition is correct. But, here the correctness of the definition is obvious by its construction.

> In   order to show that $p_k$ is a probability measure, we have to show the following
>
> (1) $\quad p_k\in[0,1]\qquad\qquad 0\leq k\leq  m$
>
> (2) $\quad P(S)=1$

Ad (1):

> Since for $0\leq k\leq m$
>
> \begin{align*}
> 0&\leq\binom{m}{k}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{m-k}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^k\\
> &=p_k\\ 
> &\leq \sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{m-k}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^k=1
> \end{align*}
>   (1) is valid.

Ad (2):

> The outcomes $k_1,k_2\in S$ with different $k_1,k_2$ are pairwise disjoint. So,    we  obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> P(S)&=P\left(\bigcup_{k=0}^m(X=k )\right)
> =\sum_{k=0}^mP(X=k)
> =\sum_{k=0}^m p_k\\
> &= \sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{m-k}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^k=1\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>   and (2) is fulfilled.

Finally:

> We have to show that $p_k$ is a $\text{binomial}(\frac{1}{n},m)$ distribution.
>
> A *[binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Probability_mass_function)* of type $(\frac{1}{n},m)$ is per definitionem
>   \begin{align*}
> P(X=k)=\binom{m}{k}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^k\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{m-k}
> \end{align*}
>   This is precisely  the  formula in (1), so  we are done.

**Conclusion:** The proof itself is rather easy, since we have to do only few calculations.  Despite that the challenge is to *precisely* specify what is given, what is the sample space, what is the probability measure and to get a certain familiarity how these objects interact.

Comment: thank you very much for your great help. However, I'm not sure where you got the property $(2)$ from? I think we are supposed to show $P(S) = 1$. Now, for property $(3)$, I am not sure how could you pull out the union sign out of $P(S) = P(\bigcup_{k=0}^{m} (X=k))$. Because that allows you to rewrite it as the sum, which essentially THE SAME as applying inclusion-exclusion principle in this case, as {X=k} are disjoint sets for $k=0,1,2,...m$. Did I miss something here?

Comment: @user177196: Property (2) stems from $p_k\in [0,1]$. I've merged (1) and (2) into one single case $p_k\in[0,1]$. And you are right of course regarding $P(S)$ and the union sign. --> corrected. Since the events are pairwise disjoint, we do not need *explicitely* apply the inclusion-exclusion principle. I have streamlined the answer somewhat to enhance readability. Regards,

Comment: thank you so much for your patience, and your confirmation on the union sign of $P(S)$. Really appreciate it! The 3 properties I try to verify come from here (http://www.randomservices.org/random/prob/Probability.html) I think if $p_k$ is defined as the probability, $p_k$ should be $\leq 1$ already, so we don't need to show it here.

Comment: @user177196: You're welcome. In case $p_k\leq 1$ is part of the assumption, you don't need to prove it. So, you're right. :-)